# vee: validate with required fails when setting checkbox value programmatically

Tags: vee-validate

This: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-glade-tg7ev

ValidationObserver works when clicking a, b or c checkbox. But when value is inserted in array programmatically (click button), the ValidattionObserver doesn't detect it. Is that an error and I think the valid property from ValidationObserver should change?

Ken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test the validation when setting the values programatically, you have to call the following piece of code, just after you've updated the value, and put a `ref="observer"` on the `ValidationObserver` component.

```
this.$refs.observer.validate();
```

Updated codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-pine-mrrlm

Comment: Yes, I got it to work that way, but all data is reactive so I think vee-validate should pick that up. Thanks anyway